# Send xml request to webservice from php

Tags: php, web-services, php-curl

I am trying to send a xml-request to a webservice from PHP, using curl.
I do not know much about the webservice.

When I am running this code, the result allways seams to be "Completed with no errors."

The xml should be valid for the webservice, but I am not able to get a response. If i dump $data it is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
$request = build_xml();
$length = strlen($request);

$url = "https://sonwin-test.forsyningsit.dk/XMLBasisWS.svc?wsdl";

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10000);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10000);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Contant-Type: application/xml', 'Content-Length: ' .$length));

$data = curl_exec($curl);

if ($data === false) {
    $err = 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    print $err;
} else {
    curl_close($curl);
    print 'Completed with no errors.';
}

return $data;
```

UPDATE:
It seems that i have been getting af HTTP 415 error because of the content type. Now the content-type is application/soap+xml. But now I get at HTTP 400 Bad Request.

Comment: PHP has a SOAP client which can autoconfigure itself based on the WSDL.  You might want to look into using that instead of a roll-your-own solution.

Comment: I have tried using the PHP SOAP client, but i keeps giving me a Soap Action error no matter what i call.